# Online or Offline tool to align html script into same line and remove extra-spaces?

Tags: html, line-breaks, text-alignment, formatter, text-align

Is there any online or offline tool to align HTML scripts into same line and remove extra-spaces for example:

Before:

```
<head>
  <h1>This is my page.</h1>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h4>Text example.</h4>
  </body>
```

After:

```
<head><h1>This is my page.</h1></head><body><h4>Text example.</h4></body>
```

I want a tool because my scripts are too large to do this manually, if so it will take me some time to finish.

Comment: The posted answer is probably fine, but _eventually_ you will want to explore things like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) -- these are tools that can be used to create "build tasks" that run automatically or on command, and can do things like concatenating/minifying your HTML, CSS and Javascript.  This is probably a ways down the road for you, but worth knowing about today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your code to minified verson
Tools - http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-white-spaces.php
Online - http://www.textfixer.com/html/compress-html-compression.php

Comment: First option is not working as my wish, and the only problem for the second that's not removing the extra-spaces, but I'm gonna check now, other tool for removing the extras.

Comment: It worked with this: http://jsbeautifier.org/ - Used first for the removing the extra-spaces